# Main table with hundreds vs few smaller

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, database-design

I was wondering which approach is better for designing databases?

I have currently one big table (97 columns per row) with references to lookup tables where I could.

Wouldn't it be better for performance to group some columns into smaller tables and add them key columns for referencing one whole row?

Comment: **[check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10931849/1425057)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split up your table into several parts, you'll need additional joins to get all your columns for a single row - that will cost you time.

97 columns isn't much, really - I've seen way beyond 100.

It all depends on how your data is being used - if your row just has 97 columns, all the time, and needs to 97 columns - then it really hardly ever makes sense to split those up into various tables.

It might make sense if:

- you can move some "large" columns (like `XML`, `VARCHAR(MAX)` etc.) into a separate table, if you don't need those all the time -> in that case, your "basic" row becomes smaller and your basic table will perform better - as long as you don't need those extra large column
- you can move away some columns to a separate table that aren't always present, e.g. columns that might be "optional" and only present for e.g. 20% of the rows - in that case, you might save yourself some processing for the remaining 80% of the cases where those columns aren't needed.

Comment: @marc_s So it seems that SQL Server better handle operations on ints rather than text-based values?

Comment: @AdrianK.: SQL Server handles operations better the smaller the data type is, and prefers fixed-length types (like INT) over variable-length since the fixed-length types have less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to group relevant columns into different tables. This will improve the performance of your database as well as your ease of use as the programmer. You should try to first find all the different relationships between your columns and following that you should attempt to break everything into tables while keeping in mind these relationships (using primary keys, forking keys, references and so forth).Try to create a diagram as this http://www.simple-talk.com/iwritefor/articlefiles/354-image008.gif and take it from there.

Comment: Not necessarily! Having multiple "parts" to a single row also means additional JOIN's, and those aren't "free" - it costs time to join tables together!

Comment: @marc_s Yeah but when you're querying a table with 97 cols for one cell it's far better to have a smaller table. Plus for organizational purposes it also makes more sense. (of course depending on the data itself..if the data is all relevant on all 97 cols then keep it this way but I doubt that)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your data is denormalized it is likely best to keep all the columns in the same table.  SQL Server reads pages into the buffer pool from individual tables.  Thus you will have the cost of the joins on every access even if the pages accessed are already in the buffer pool.   If you access just a few rows of the data per query with a key then an index will serve that query fine with all columns in the same table.  Even if you will scan a large percentage of the rows (> 1% of a large table) but only a few of the 97 columns you are still better off keeping the columns in the same table as you can use a non clustered index that covers the query.  However, if the data is heavily denormalized then normalizing it, which by definition breaks it into many tables based upon the rules of normalization to eliminate redundancy, will result in much improved performance and you will be able to write queries to access only the specific data elements you need.